# Bug on astype pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timedelta

I am working with timedeltas and it seems this code

`copy_for_U.Time.astype('timedelta64[m]',copy=False);`

does not change the dataframe - as it should, if I understood correctly from the doc, where it says:

> `Signature: full_df.Time.astype(dtype, copy=True, raise_on_error=True, **kwargs)
>   Docstring:
>   Cast object to input numpy.dtype
>   Return a copy when copy = True (be really careful with this!)`

Comment: I believe the change will be made in place only if it can be made without creating a copy. The change of `dtype` you require here is "too much" of a change, so I think it (silently) returns a copy. This really is underlying numpy behaviour, see [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).

Comment: IIUC do you need `copy_for_U.Time = copy_for_U.Time.astype('timedelta64[m]')` ?

Comment: @jezrael yeah, that's what I did and it worked...but I wasted an afternoon looking somewhere else, as I couldn't plot

Answer (score 1):

In order for the changes to be applied to the dataframe, one needs to assign the dataframe to the variable one wants (or pass `inplace=True` - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43893457/7109869) may be a nice thread to read).

Also, when doing that, you don't need to pass the [`copy=False`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), as [@jezrael suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566760/bug-on-astype-pandas#comment70338164_41566760).

Given that, this should solve your problem

```
copy_for_U.Time = copy_for_U.Time.astype('timedelta64[m]')
```